# Detecting table cell collisions on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, dom

I'm attempting to use jQuery to allow me reduce the size of a table's text before any table content exceeds the with of its parent column on window resize. I know I can easily check the width of cell content against its parent table cell to detect collisions, but this method seems inefficient given that this might need to be done across 1000's of table cells every 100ms or so as the user resizes.

Does anyone have a more efficient method?

Pseudocode below:

```
On resize (throttled)
    If any table content has less than 10px until it exceeds the width of its containing column
        Do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to check every cell in the table, just the top row of cells.

Alternatively, you could set a min-width of the table cells, then use css3 `text-overflow: ellipsis`

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    min-width: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

What might be an even better alternative is making a responsive data table. Check out [this article](http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-table-roundup/) on CSS-Tricks showing different methods on dealing with wide table data.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to preserve on-screen display of content as long as possible before going responsive. After the font size decreases down to a defined minimum I'm going to snap to a scrollable table view.

Comment: More importantly - what if cells in rows further down the table have longer width than the first row?

Comment: The entire table will resize to fit the widest content.